# Xamarin Forms - Como tornar o Datime.Now dinâmico?

Tags: datetime, xamarin-forms, binding, dinâmico

Como tornar o **Datime.Now** dinâmico no xamarin forms ?
preciso que o tempo continue correndo. Neste caso está parado.

Eu tenho um Label que captura os dados de uma classe

```
Label Text="{Binding data}" TextColor="Blue" >HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>

public static Tempo getTempo()
{
            var tempo = new Tempo() { data = DateTime.Now };
            return tempo;
}
```

no fim eu instancio

```
 public EstiloDinamico()
 {
      InitializeComponent();
      var tempo = tempoViewModel.getTempo();
      tvm = new tempoViewModel(tempo);
      BindingContext = tvm;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa dar um **setProperty** para informar a view que teve uma modificação na variável
implementa a classe : **BindableBase**
e um exemplo de como ficaria sua variável

```
private string _title;
public string Title
{
    get { return _title; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _title, value); }
}
```

sempre que houver uma alteração dentro da variável ela vai sinalizar para a view e vai ser alterado.